# jqコマンドでJSONの入れ子配列からcsv出力して値を取得する方法

Tags: json, csv, jq

やりたい事: jqコマンドで欲しいデータだけcsv出力したい

```
    {
  "jsonrpc": "2.0",
  "result": [
    {
      "hostid": "00001",
      "host": "testserver",
      "groups": [
        {
          "groupid": "1",
          "name": "host"
        },
        {
          "groupid": "2",
          "name": "〇階×室"
        }
      ],
      "inventory": {
        "hostid": "3",
        "notes": "△機種"
      },
      "interfaces": [
        {
          "ip": "0.0.0.0"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

下記コマンドで、入れ子になっているgroups内の要素2(groupid2,〇階×室)、inventoryの(hostid,△機種)、interfacesの(0.0.0.0)も出力したいのですが、やり方がわかりません。

↓現時点

> cat test.json | jq -r '.result[] | [.hostid,.host] | @csv'
>   "00001","testserver"

どのようにコマンドを打てば下記のような出力ができるでしょうか？

"00001","testserver","2","〇階×室","3","△機種","0.0.0.0"

Comment: `groupid` に関しては `select` を使うとよいかと。`cat test.json | jq -r '.result[]|[.hostid, .host, (.groups[]|select(.groupid=="2")[]), .inventory[], .interfaces[].ip]|@csv'`

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。
申し訳ありません。質問が間違っていたのですが、上記のコマンドで
groupidが2の項目、は抜き出す事ができたのですが
上記のようなデータが下に続いている場合、
groups[]内の2つ目の{}内のみを全て抜き出す事は可能でしょうか?
もしくは、1つ目込みでもできるでしょうか?

Comment: はい、その場合は `cat test.json | jq -r '.result[]|[.hostid, .host, .groups[1][], .inventory[], .interfaces[].ip]|@csv'` とすればよいかと思います。

Comment: ありがとうございます!欲しい所だけ取れました。
解決しました。追加の質問などでお手数をおかけして申し訳ありません。